# A fast way to make clothes

Tags: makehuman

I'd like to know if there is an addon, a tool or something else to make clothes quickly, like makehuman or Manuel bastioni lab as regards making persons.

Thanks

Comment: Cloth Seving Springs in Cloth simulation is pretty neat tool for easy creation of cloths.[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q06lPp2PNG4) you find nice tutorial on the topic. [Marvelous Designer](http://www.marvelousdesigner.com/) would be probably a better choice if you aim for fast, easy solution and you don't care too much about geometry.

Comment: Thank you for answering; is there a program like Marvelous Designer for free?

Comment: No. But if it's not for commercial project, you can use MD for free.

Comment: You might want to check out [Rich Colburn's tools](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yHGz7nEI23E)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, MakeHuman does include Blender add-ons, such as MakeClothes.  If you download MakeHuman for free, then you can use this add-on in Blender to make clothes off of a MakeHuman base mesh created in the add-on.  You can also use MakeHuman to create the clothes from a library, and expand the selection with free downloads on MakeHuman’s website.

Answer (score 0):

Good instruments for making cloths provides by this addon:

https://gumroad.com/l/GarmentTool

Note, it requires 2.80 version.